# "'int' object is not iterable" in while

Tags: python, integer, iteration, ipython

```
def rect_extend(x):
  m, n = 1
  while 1 < x:
    m = m + 1
    n = n + 1
  return m, n
```

This simple function returns:

> 'int' object is not iterable

error in iPython. I don't know why it does this, `while` function doesn't work - condition seems to be `true`.

(**while**'s condition was simplified on purpose; original code doesn't have it)

Comment: By the way, you seem to have created an infinite loop unless you never intended to escape the `while` loop.

Comment: It counts how many rectangles can I build in bigger rectangle in Cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
m = 1
n = 1
```

or

```
m = n = 1
```

instead of `m, n = 1`.

This (sequence unpacking)[http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences]:

```
x, y = z
```

does something different to what you seem to think it does.

It actually means this:

```
x = z[0]    # The first item in z
y = z[1]    # The second element of z
```

For instance, you could do this:

```
x, y, z = (1, 2, 4)
```

Then:

```
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
4
```

In your case, you this doesn't work, because `1` is an integer, it doesn't have elements, hence the error.

Useful features of sequence unpacking combined with tuples (and the splat operator - `*`):

This:

```
a, b = b, a
```

swaps the values of `a` and `b`.

Unpacking `range`, useful for constants:

```
>>> RED, GREEN, BLUE = range(3)
>>> RED
0
>>> GREEN
1
>>> BLUE
2
```

The splat operator:

```
>>> first, *middle, last = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
>>> first
1
>>> middle
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> last
9
```

Comment: In any case, would the downvoter care to explain the problem with my answer?

Comment: Just added comment on this issue in main post; problem is solved, big thanks to sweeneyrod.

Answer (score 6):

When you do `m, n = 1` this is called [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and it works like this:

```
>>> m, n = ('a','b')
>>> m
'a'
>>> n
'b'
```

Since `1` is an integer not a tuple, you get this weird error; because Python cannot "step through" (or *iterate*) an integer to unpack it. That's why the error is 'int' object is ***not iterable***

Comment: The docs you link to call this *sequence* unpacking rather than *tuple* unpacking, emphasing that the RHS doesn't have to be exactly a tuple. And nor does it have to be a sequence - it can be any iterable with the right number of elements.