# Type error: Int object is not iterable error [For loop]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is an exercise I have found on Kaggle which defines my purpose as:

> We'd like to host these wine reviews on our website, but a rating
> system ranging from 80 to 100 points is too hard to understand - we'd
> like to translate them into simple star ratings. A score of 95 or
> higher counts as 3 stars, a score of at least 85 but less than 95 is 2
> stars. Any other score is 1 star.
>
> Also, the Canadian Vintners Association bought a lot of ads on the
> site, so any wines from Canada should automatically get 3 stars,
> regardless of points.
>
> Create a series `star_ratings` with the number of stars corresponding
> to each review in the dataset.

Data.head( ):[image]

And I wrote this code with the hope to serve my purpose:

```
def stars(reviews):
for i,pons in enumerate(reviews.points):
    if pons < 85:
        reviews.points[i] = "1 star"
    elif pons <95:
        reviews.points[i] = "2 stars"
    elif (pons >= 95):
        reviews.points[i] = "3 stars"
for i,cons in reviews.country:
    if cons == "Canada":
        reviews.points[i] = "3 stars"

star_ratings = reviews.apply(stars, axis = "columns")
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19752647/11485262) did not work for me as I keep getting the

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Why my for loop keeps on giving me this error?

Comment: It looks like `reviews.points` is an integer.  You can't iterate over a single integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`df.apply(axis='columns')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), the provided function will be applied to *each row* of the input DataFrame.

The `reviews` argument holds a `pd.Series` representing a *single row*.  Therefore `reviews.points` is a single cell, not a column.

Here's one way that you could rewrite the function:

```
def stars(review):
    if review.points < 85:
        review.points = "1 star"
    elif review.points < 95:
        review.points = "2 stars"
    elif review.points >= 95:
        review.points = "3 stars"
    if review.country == "Canada":
        review.points = "3 stars"

star_ratings = reviews.apply(stars, axis="columns")
```

Another way, which will be much more performant, is to ditch the `apply` and use vectorized instructions:

```
star_ratings = reviews.copy()
star_ratings['points'] = pd.cut(star_ratings['points'], bins=[-np.inf, 85, 95, np.inf], labels=['1 star', '2 stars', '3 stars'])
star_ratings.loc[star_ratings['country'] == 'Canada', 'points'] = '3 stars'
```